# How to model and implement a class that may inherit from different classes?

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, class-diagram

I have the following 'entities' in my model: `DataItem`, `String`, `Integer` and `Argument`.
I am unsure how to create a class diagram which reflects the following aspects:

- A `String` is a `DataItem`
- An `Integer` is a `DataItem`
- An `Argument` can be a `String`, an `Integer`, or a `DataItem` (i.e. neither `String` nor `Integer`).

Do I have to create the additional Classes "StringArgument", "IntegerArgument", and "DataItemArgument" or is there a better solution? I assume that making Argument inherit from `String`, `Integer`, and `DataItem` is not a good solution, right?

In general: How do I model cases in which a class inherits either from one class, or from another?

PS: The implementation will be in Python 2.7 but I am interested in the general problem so any solutions referring to other languages are fine.

Comment: Pick a language. Java != C# != C++. Also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You could have `Argument` hold a `DataItem` pointer/reference (depends on language) and `String` and `Integer` inherit off `DataItem`.

Comment: In Java, multiple inheritance is not permitted, but it is in C++ (sorry for the C# there are not too)

Comment: @JFPicard multiple inheritance is not allowed in C# either.

Comment: @JFPicard In C# you can only inherit multiple interfaces though right? Or I should say "implement" multiple interfaces.

Comment: @CoryKramer: It is a general question regarding the creation of a class diagram. I removed the language tags.

Comment: @stackoverflowwww So then tag **none** of those languages if your question isn't specifically related to them.

Comment: @Borgleader You can implement multiple interfaces in C#, but I believe you can do that in Java also.

Comment: @CoryKramer They were suggested automatically by SO. But nevertheless I will consider your hint next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to separate the `Argument` concept from that of an item of data. You're quite right that `String` and `Integer` are both `DataItem`s, but I'm not convinced that an `Argument` is a `DataItem`. It just holds one. This naturally leads to:

```
    DataItem
     ^    ^
    /      \
   |       |
String    Integer
```

And `Argument` would hold a pointer or reference (or whatever the implementation language supports) to `DataItem`. An argument may contain more than just (one) data (item); for example, if it's a command-line argument to a program, you may want to retain positional information. It therefore makes sense to me that an argument *contains* the data, rather than the argument *being* the data.

```
class Argument {
  public:
    // etc
  private:
    DataItem* data;
};
```

(Note that this approach can be implemented in most languages that support object-oriented programming).

You can have `StringArgument` and `IntegerArgument` as separate types, holding a member of the relevant type, though the relevancy of doing so will vary depending on the situation and on the implementation language (e.g. in Python, you wouldn't care whether it was an `Integer` or a `String`, so long as it subscribed to the interface prescribed by `DataItem`). In C++, you could use templates to provide an `Argument` class as a generic container:

```
template <typename data_type>
class Argument {
  public:
    // etc.
  private:
   data_type data;
};

typedef Argument<String> StringArgument; // "composes a" String
typedef Argument<Integer> IntegerArgument; // "composes an" Integer
```

In other words, precisely how you implement this will depend on the facilities provided by the language you choose, but the design is simpler if you don't consider an argument to be "a kind of" data, but instead to be "a container (or holder) of data".

As another example, and again in C++, you could have your `Argument` types inherit from the relevant data type...

```
template <typename data_type>
class Argument : public data_type {
  // etc.
};

typedef Argument<String> StringArgument; // "is a" String
typedef Argument<Integer> IntegerArgument; // "is an" Integer
```

(Note that this approach requires a language to support generic programming in a sense similar to that of C++ templates).

This goes back to the idea of an argument *being* the data, rather than containing the data, however.

Comment: You are right, it is essentially about 'being' something vs. 'containing' something. And you are also right than in my case an Argument is rather a container.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your generic class in this is `Argument`, and that your three other classes should inherit from it.

That would indeed require wrapper classes for `String` and `Integer`.

Your question reminds me of the Composite Design Pattern, but I am not sure whether it is what you want.